# Q# Intellisense Errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, q#

I can build my Q# projects fine, but VS 2017 (v. 15.9.4) has the Intellisense errors code QS6103 of "No namespace with that name exists." for my first two "open" statements shown below. I have tried with both the "0.3.1811.1501" and "0.3.1811.2802" versions of the SDK and Canon.

```
 namespace Quantum.QSharpApplication1
{
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;

    operation HelloQ () : Unit {
        Message("Hello quantum world!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of .NET Core do you have installed? (You can check using `dotnet --version`)

I ran into similar problems with Q# IntelliSense not recognizing library namespaces, with .NET Core 2.1.500 and 2.1.403, but with 2.1.402 it works fine. I had to uninstall the higher versions though.

Comment: I have 2.2.101 installed. I guess I'll have to downgrade .Net core for this... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It worked! Or at least I don't get intellisense errors anymore. Don't really get intellisense though....

Comment: @LWoodyiii Do you get no IntelliSense at all - no hover info for library functions, no red squiggly lines for incorrect syntax, nothing at all? I did get that after switching to 2.1.402

Comment: I do get hover info and red squiggly lines for incorrect syntax, guess I had too high expectations :)