# VSCode Q# extension installation issue?

Tags: visual-studio-code, q#

[It was suggested to me to ask this here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/quantum-docs-pr/issues/346), I have no issue on running `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run` on a just created project folder but VSCode Q# extension fails to work like this and it doesn't give any good pointer what has went wrong.

```
[Error - 10:35:54 PM] MSBuild error in /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/NuGet.targets(123,7): The "RestoreForceEvaluate" parameter is not supported by the "RestoreTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
[Error - 10:35:54 PM] MSBuild error in /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/NuGet.targets(114,5): The "RestoreTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters. 
[Error - 10:35:54 PM] Failed to restore project '.../Bell/Bell.csproj'.
[Error - 10:35:54 PM] MSBuild error in /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.2.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5): The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Frameworks, Version=4.9.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)
File name: 'NuGet.Frameworks, Version=4.9.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task, Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromMemory(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)


[Error - 10:35:54 PM] Failed to resolve assembly references for project
```

I believe I should've raised this on VSCode Q# extension bug tracker but I can't find the tracker and as mentioned initially I am suggested to ask here, so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be another manifestation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925337/q-intellisense-errors) - Q# IntelliSense is not happy with .NET Core versions above 2.1.402, and looks like your .NET Core version is 2.2.100. We're working on a fix; meanwhile, downgrading to earlier version should help.

Update: This issue should have been fixed with QDK release 0.4.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, but with 3.1 sdk. Any updates?

Comment: This is probably something new and interesting, related to update from .NET Core 3.0 to 3.1. Could you please open a new question with all the details so that somebody can look into it specifically?

Comment: Should I raise an issue on Github?